# Express static server - set the dir folder

Tags: node.js, express

I create simple express static server.

```
app.get("/media/:filename/" ,express.static(__dirname + /media/));
```

my problem is that if I want to get a file from the server the file 
need to be under the media/media folder.

I know that I can write

```
app.get("/media/:filename/" ,express.static(__dirname));
```

and it would work, but I look for another solution that I dont have to create the root folder to be the static server root.

I though to use redirect to another path but I think this is not good solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write :

```
app.get("/media" ,express.static(__dirname + /media/));
```

then server will serve all files from root media directory.

if you write url:

```
http://localhost:3000/media/kitten.jpg
```

it will search file in root media/kitten.jpg

if you have route :

```
app.get("/static" ,express.static(__dirname + /public/));
```

it doesn't means that your files are in static/public.
It means that you map `static` url to `public` directory

it is describe here:
http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html